# XPATH Filtering elements in different inner path using condition

Tags: java, xpath

Team, I am going through multiple XPATH tutorials, but not able to achieve the below expectation using one XPathExpression.

How to get PostpaidInformation --> ActiveValue and Date value of AccountNumber=AC-12 ..?

```
<params>
    <param>
        <value>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>PrepaidInformation</name>
                    <value>
                        <struct>
                            <member>
                                <name>activationStatus</name>
                                <value>
                                    <boolean>1</boolean>
                                </value>
                            </member>
                        </struct>
                    </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>MixedInformation</name>
                    <value>
                        <struct>
                            <member>
                                <name>activationStatus</name>
                                <value>
                                    <boolean>0</boolean>
                                </value>
                            </member>
                        </struct>
                    </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>PostpaidInformation</name>
                    <value>
                        <array>
                            <data>
                                <value>
                                    <struct>
                                        <member>
                                            <name>ActiveValue</name>
                                            <value>
                                                <string>60</string>
                                            </value>
                                        </member>
                                        <member>
                                            <name>Date</name>
                                            <value>
                                                <string>20170225T12:00:00</string>
                                            </value>
                                        </member>
                                        <member>
                                            <name>AccountNumber</name>
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>AC-12</i4>
                                            </value>
                                        </member>
                                    </struct>
                                </value>
                                <value>
                                    <struct>
                                        <member>
                                            <name>ActiveValue</name>
                                            <value>
                                                <string>23</string>
                                            </value>
                                        </member>
                                        <member>
                                            <name>Date</name>
                                            <value>
                                                <string>20170225T12:00:00</string>
                                            </value>
                                        </member>
                                        <member>
                                            <name>AccountNumber</name>
                                            <value>
                                                <i4>AC-13</i4>
                                            </value>
                                        </member>
                                    </struct>
                                </value>
                            </data>
                        </array>
                    </value>
                </member>
            </struct>
        </value>
    </param>
</params>
```

Note i have to match PostpaidInformation, then match on AccountNumber = AC-12. If it matches prints all the information about that account.

Maybe what i need is `//methodResponse/params/param/value/struct/member/name[text()=\"PostpaidInformation\"]` TRAVERSE all the accounts within this till finding `AccountNumber=AC-12`, if found then back out one level from `member/value` to reach `<struct>` to iterate all the `<member>` inside that struct.

Expected Output is NodeSet of below to traverse.

```
                                    <member>
                                        <name>ActiveValue</name>
                                        <value>
                                            <string>60</string>
                                        </value>
                                    </member>
                                    <member>
                                        <name>Date</name>
                                        <value>
                                            <string>20170225T12:00:00</string>
                                        </value>
                                    </member>
                                    <member>
                                        <name>AccountNumber</name>
                                        <value>
                                            <i4>AC-12</i4>
                                        </value>
                                    </member>
```

Actual answer from

Anderson is

```
//member/name[text()="PostpaidInformation"]/following-sibling:: 
value/array/data/value/struct[member[name="AccountNumber"]/value/i4="AC-12"]
```

har07 is

```
//member[name='PostpaidInformation']//struct[member[name='AccountNumber' and value/i4='AC-12']]/member
```

Comment: Could you update question with exact output you want to get?

Comment: @Andersson Updated Q. I just want a NodeSet of name=PrepaidInformation ../array/data/value/struct for AccountNumber=AC-12.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try:

```
//member/name[text()="PostpaidInformation"][1]/following-sibling::value/array/data/value/struct/member
```

This `XPath` should return 3 `member` nodes:

```
<member>
    <name>ActiveValue</name>
    <value>
         <string>60</string>
    </value>
</member>
<member>
   <name>Date</name>
   <value>
        <string>20170225T12:00:00</string>
   </value>
</member>
<member>
   <name>AccountNumber</name>
   <value>
        <i4>AC-12</i4>
   </value>
</member>
```

If you want to retrieve `<struct>` that contains those 3 `<member>`:

```
//member/name[text()="PostpaidInformation"]/following-sibling::value/array/data/value/struct[member[name[.="AccountNumber"]/following-sibling::value/i4="AC-12"]]
```

Comment: Thank you! And where is the match for AC-12 among the array..? i think [1] is index of the array ..? then i am not sure AC-12 will always be array index [1]. Please help.

Comment: You mean you want to match **first** `<name>PostpaidInformation</name>` **only if** following `<value>` sibling has Account number = `"AC-12"`?

Comment: No. <name>PostpaidInformation</name> will be only one. But that contains multiple accounts. among that how to match a account which has  Account number = "AC-12" ..?

Comment: Does this do a trick `//member/name[text()="PostpaidInformation"][1]/following-sibling::value/array/data/value/struct[./member/value/i4="AC-12"]/member`?

Comment: Sure i will check and revert you in 2 mins, but what is [1] here at `text()="PostpaidInformation"][1]`

Comment: Oh... You can remove the index (`[1]`). I guess I misunderstood your `i have to match first PostpaidInformation`

Comment: Thanks. This is printing the siblings till "AC-12‌​" after that siblings are missed. Assume if <member> <name>AccountNumber</name> is before ActiveValue and Date then these values are missed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137329/discussion-between-andersson-and-kanagavelu-sugumar).

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible XPath (wrapped for readability) :

```
//member[name='PostpaidInformation']
//struct[member[name='AccountNumber' and value/i4='AC-12']]
/member
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/KT0_-eGd5)</kbd>**

**brief explanation :**

- **`//member[name='PostpaidInformation']`** : search for `member` element where `name` child value equals 'PostpaidInformation'
- **`//struct[member[name='AccountNumber' and value/i4='AC-12']]`** : within such `member` element, search for descendant `struct` element containing child element `member` where `name` equals 'AccountNumber' and `value/i4` equals 'AC-12'
- **`/member`** : from such `struct`, return all child elements named `member`

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: Yours is neat and clean :)